# Iterate Through Folders within Folders

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, iterator, arcgis-10.3

I am having some trouble creating a model that will iterate through folders and subfolders. I want to be able to have the top level folder as a parameter and then have the code go through each of the sub folders and complete an action.

I have working code for the action I'm looking to complete and I am able to create an iteration to go through one folder, but I want to be able to go through 18 folders and run my script on every .mxd within each folder.

Here is the model that runs within one folder.
[image]

I want this to run through the 18 folders that I have.

Any ideas? I can run this either as a model or a script.

Comment: If you're comfortable with Python, you can use arcpy.da.Walk (10.1+) or os.walk.

Comment: probably better off doing this in a script using @phloem suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to find all the mxds in a directory tree using the os module:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/junk'):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.mxd':
            print 'It is an MXD!'
```

Comment: In using this then, It works the same as any normal script when it find the .mxd? So if i have 2 mxds with the same table, and want to perform the same task on both, I would simply use the functions within the loop?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: In this example, you did a simple print, but could arcpy.SearchCursor(for example) be used to find amount of X attributes within a certain field possible be used in there as well?

Comment: For each file found in the directory, a new path is placed in the 'file' variable. If it happens to be an mxd, it passes into the deepest loop (with the print statement). From there, access the mxd by referring to the path found in the 'file' variable. So, yes, you can do whatever you would normally do to an mxd file, by referencing the 'file' variable. I think you may be confusing walking through a file directory with using a cursor to loop through data.